# What is THE UNIT in a unit test? And what should it be?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests

Is a unit a class or a component(more than one class)?

What should be a unit test? How granular should be a unit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term (similar to many other things associated with Agile) is overloaded (means different things to different people). It has undergone a lot of flux and is now subjective. Some have come up with a new term microtests to prevent confusion.

Earlier it was meant to mean function-level white-box testing. As a rule of thumb, a unit is usually a behavior exposed by a class (usually as a method).
Among TDD practitioners, there are two camps

- interaction-based testing isolates the class from its dependencies (assuming a certain contract between the two). The dependencies are tested via their unit tests. The unit test specifies how the unit behaves w.r.t. to others given certain stimuli
- state-based testing tests a class along with its real dependencies.

My current understanding is that it's a deliberate choice per unit-test ; one style does not fit all.

Answer (score 5):

A unit is the smallest testable part of the application, usually a function.

Comment: When I try to test the function and the function has dependencies to other functions (within the same class/assembly) is this also a unit test when I do not mock out the depencies (functions that are called from the to test function) ?

Comment: Well as i said its usually a function, as its not always possible to isolate each function to be unit-testable alone, specially where you have some existing application including legacy code where you want to start with UT, therefor the theory to write the test before you write the function, and to write small independent functions which do a clear defined piece of work. Any way the best point to start with UT is on design time. See these  nice article on isolating dependencies: http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/42148/1763/page/2 (note the links at the end of the page)

Comment: @Rookian: take a look at the "Which dependencies to isolate?" part on this article. http://java.dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-fundamentals

Answer (score 3):

I would put it like this: a unit in a unit test is an entity for which a defined output is expected for a known input. The level of granularity however can vary dramatically: from a function to a class to the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a class. It can be more than one class. It can be the entire system. It's a logical piece that takes input and gives output -- however those are defined for that component.

Comment: So when I 'm writing a test that tests a method that has multiple (within the same component/ i.e. assembly) dependencies (classes) it is still a unit test?

Comment: @Rookian for sure. Usually you will "mock up" those external dependencies with classes/methods that return appropriate values for that test. For example, if you're writing a unit test for a method to see if it properly handles an error condition in one of its dependencies, you would create a mock class that generates that error condition, and then your unit test would confirm that your method is properly handling the error.

Comment: If you test dependencies, it is called integration test

Comment: @Shaggy Frog keep attention that I was not talking about EXTERNAL dependencies. The dependencies are in the same assembly.

Comment: @Tuomas Hietanen: Does it matter if the depencies are within the same assembly (external/internal depencies) or is your statement in general valid?

Answer (score 2):

It could also be smaller; a unit test for a single method.